# How to factor ideals in a quadratic number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $w=\sqrt{-5}$; we work in $\mathbb Z[w]$; which is not a PID or UFD.

Now in Sage (3) factors in $(3,1+w)(3,2+w)$ and (7) in $(7,3+w)(7,4+w)$.

Please explain clearly how factorization of ideals in a quadratic non-PID works.

Is it because this is a non-PID quadratic numberfield that the ideal factors in two non-principal ideals?

The numbers 11 and 13 are irreducible as 3 and 7 are, yet (11) and (13) do not factor as ideals. How do I determine the difference in this context?

EDIT:
implementation of solution provided by Dietrich Burde (second cell in Sage Worksheet)

[image: worksheet]

Comment: You might want to read [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/quadraticgrad.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorisation of ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a quadratic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ works as follows. Let $D$ be the discriminant, i.e., $D=d$ or $D=4d$.

**Theorem:** Let $p>2$ be a prime and $K$ a quadratic number field as above.

1.) If the Kronecker symbol $(D/p)=0$ then $(p)=(p,\sqrt{d})^2$ ramifies. 
2.) If the Kronecker symbol $(D/p)=1$ then $(p)=P_1P_2$ splits, with two prime ideals $P_1,P_2$. 
3.) If the Kronecker symbol $(D/p)=-1$ then $(p)$ is inert, i.e., remains prime.

In the second case, $P_1=(p, x+\sqrt{d})$ and $P_2=(p, x-\sqrt{d})$ with an integer $x$ such that $D\equiv x^2 (p)$. For $p=2$ there is a similar result.

This gives a formula how to factorize ideals, regardless whether or not $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID or UFD.

Comment: Looks awesome, very clear indeed! Will go through my books and see why I missed this.

Comment: Your books probably say "Legendre symbol" rather than "Kronecker symbol." And your CAS might expect "Jacobi symbol."

Comment: I mentioned Sage in the question, in Sage Legendre symbol is referred to as kronecker

Comment: I added a follow-up question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044017/how-to-factor-ideal-65537-in-zi

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica has always had JacobiSymbol, whereas KroneckerSymbol was introduced in Version 6.0.

Comment: It seems to me like this answer is not quite so applicable to non-UFDs. For example, consider $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{30})$. We have $\left(\frac{30}{17}\right) = 1$, yet 17 is irreducible: how do you solve $(x - y\sqrt{30})(x + y\sqrt{30}) = 17$?

Comment: Robert, see the image of the Sage worksheet after the edit in the question. The method provided in this answer also works for the case you provided.

Comment: Consider using `\bmod` to format the equivalence better: $D \equiv x^2 \bmod p$